# select all method to select all checkbox in listview android not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have custom adapter to populating listview with both names and checkbox on each item. Now I have added a button on top of list to enable select all items, but somehow it is not working I cant figure it how where I am wrong. Neither it is throwing any error. here is my code. `

```
send_show12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    //              flag = !flag;
                    //lv = get
                    int size = lv.getCount();
                    `Log.d("This is count is at button listener", ""+size);

                    if(lv.isItemChecked(1)){
                        for(int i = 0; i<=size; i++){

                            lv.setItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        for(int i = 0; i<=size; i++){
                            lv.setItemChecked(i, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });`
```

help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you scroll the listview with checkboxes then the position of the items will change so that checked items may unchecked and unchecked items may checked.so that why the selected list items are not displayed properly.(Did you observe this issue??)
>    to resolve this issue you have to use ArrayAdapter instead of baseAdapter.
>    [Please follow this link to over come the issue.](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php#downloads)
>
> instead of PlanetsActivity class use this class remaining is same...

```
public class PlanetsActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mainListView;
//private Planet[] planets;
ArrayList<Planet> planets=new ArrayList<Planet>();
private ArrayAdapter<Planet> listAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the ListView resource.
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // When item is tapped, toggle checked properties of CheckBox and
    // Planet.

    mainListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Planet planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                    planet.toggleChecked();
                    PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) item
                            .getTag();
                    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(planet.isChecked());
                }
            });

    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            planets.clear();
            for(int i=1;i<15;i++){
                planets.add(new Planet(""+i,true));
            }

            listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(this, planets);
            mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    });

    planets.add(new Planet("1", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("2", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("3", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("4", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("5", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("6", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("7", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("8", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("9", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("10", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("11", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("12", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("13", false));
    planets.add(new Planet("14", false));


    listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(this, planets);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return planets;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to check the View which represents your item. You said you have a checkbox and a text there so I presume it's a LinearLayout. LinearLayout does not implement Checkable and hence you cannot check it.

You can either implement a subclass of LiearLayout which implements Checkable (that's not fun, and most free solutions on the web I've seen are either broken by design or incomplete such that they won't work under all circumstances) or you look up your CheckBox inside the LinearLayout in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I use a HashMap to keep track of the id's of the selected items